# como trabalhar com url amigável

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Tenho um site que não utiliza URL amigável minha URL esta assim 
http://site/download/programa?id=1&cat=113&dev=1 e nela passa os parâmetros só que quero que a URL fique assim 
http://site/download/avast-free-antivirus
no meu htaccess para tentar tornar amigável eu fiz assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download/programa.php?id=$1&cat=$2&dev=$3 [L]
```

Ai que vem o problema com faço para que quando acessar pelo nome seja puxado o id, a categoria e dev que e desenvolvedor?

E como crio a mesma condição para outra página?

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso via .htaccess deveria ficar assim a regra:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^download/avast-free-antivirus$  ./download/programa?id=1&cat=113&dev=1
```

E assim por diante, mas devo avisa-lo que essa não é a melhor forma de realizar essa função.
Não achei material bom em PT-BR, mas se souber inglês aconselho ler [esse](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) artigo

Comment: tem como tornar dinamico a parte do RewriteRule ^download/avast-free-antivirus$  ou seja quando eu digitar na url o valor seja passado para o ^download/avast-free-antivirus$ se eu digitar na url avg-antivirus ai deveria ficar assim ^download/avg-antivirus$